# cleanest way to concatenate a single string to many other element contained in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, string-concatenation

What I have:

```
string = "string"
range_list = list(range(10))
```

What I want:

```
['string0',
 'string1',
 'string2',
 'string3',
 'string4',
 'string5',
 'string6',
 'string7',
 'string8',
 'string9']
```

What I usually do:

```
import pandas as pd
(string+pd.Series(range_list).astype(str)).tolist()
```

What I would like to do:
*obtain the same expected output from the same input, without importing libraries nor using loops*

Since there is probably no way to do this complying my requests, any other solution cleaner and/or more performing than mine is well accepted. Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using list comprehension and f-string.

```py
[f"{string}{idx}" for idx in range_list]
```

Comment: exactly, but technically a list comprehension is a loop. Thanks for the solution anyway. For sure is cleaner than mine.

Comment: You ban the loop and require cleaner. Waiting for other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` with a function or a lambda to avoid using a loop.

```
def get_string(x):
    return f'string{x}'

list(map(get_string, range(10)))
```

or with a lambda:

```
list(map(lambda x: f'string{x}', range(10)))
```

For your case, you could write:

```
list(map(lambda x: f'{string}{x}', range_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, you want solutions without loops:

```
string = "string"
range_list = list(range(10))

list(map(lambda x: string + x, np.array(range_list).astype(str)))
```

Or

```
list(map(lambda x: 'string{}'.format(x), range_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too

```
string = "string"

str_list = [string + str(i) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: same as @ILS solution